# Two objects must use each other?

Tags: javascript

I have two objects, object 1 and object 2. Object 1 calls a global function which requires object 2 as an argument, yet object 2 calls the same global function with object 1 as an argument. I get the following JSLint message:

```
'obj1' was used before it was defined:        do_something(obj1);
```

The way my code works there will be no actual problems when run, but I am wondering how I can adjust my code so js-lint stops telling me this. I find JSLint useful and this message may interfere with my use of JSLint.
My code is similar to the following:

```
var obj1 = {
    foo: function () {
        bar(obj2);
    }
};
var obj2 = {
    foo: function () {
        bar(obj1);
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**
The answer below worked perfectly for me. I'm surprised I didn't think of that!

Comment: What does the code look like? And keep in mind that JSLint thinks it's a lot smarter than it really is :)

Comment: Are you using `Object.prototype` to define this function? Then, you'll need to use `obj2.do_something(obj1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be what you want:

```
var obj1, obj2;

obj1 = { // Login Prompt. Logs you in as 'devil' only!
    foo: function () {
        bar(obj2);
    }
};
obj2 = { // Login Prompt. Logs you in as 'devil' only!
    foo: function () {
        bar(obj1);
    }
};
```

Also, check out http://jshint.com/